# Putting animation in HTML

Tags: css, animation

I want to create an animation with falling objects, with different start time and different falling speed. The objects stop falling when they reach the position in the image (see below).

What's the best way to actually animate this? Should I use Adobe animator/After effects or is CSS enough?
I'm open for suggestions.

[image]

The black lines are going down even when the object stop (please ignore the shadows beneath the object)

Comment: sorry, but I don't think that this question is a good fit for SO. It is missing the context (where do you want to show the animation) and the answers will be most likely opinion based

Comment: Short answer: you can totally do this with CSS `transition`s

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```css
 
img {
transition: all 5s;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
 
}
img#abc {
left: 50px;    
 
}
img#def {
left: 120px;    
 
}
img#ghi {
left: 180px;    
 
}

img.abc {

transition: all 5s 1.5s;
top: 150px;
}
img.def {
transition: all 3s 0.5s;
top: 175px;
}
img.ghi {
transition: all 4s 1s;
top: 165px;
}
```

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
var element = document.getElementById("abc");
element.classList.add("abc");
var element = document.getElementById("def");
element.classList.add("def");
var element = document.getElementById("ghi");
element.classList.add("ghi");
}

</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> 
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDtpp.png" id="abc" height="50" width="50"/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDtpp.png" id="def" height="50" width="50"/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDtpp.png" id="ghi" height="50" width="50"/>
```

**Code for background-animation**

```css
 
   @keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 100%; }
  to { background-position: 0 0; }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 100%;; }
  to { background-position: 0 0; }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position:0 100%;; }
  to { background-position: 0 0; }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 100%;; }
  to { background-position: 0 0; }
 }

 #animate-area { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 400px; 
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/kuXpay/static.png);
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;

  animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
 }
```

```html
<div id="animate-area">
</div>
```

Comment: How can I create the lines, this is good for the objects. Thanks

Comment: Why dont you use a background-image for these lines, if they are static?

Comment: They are not static, I want to create a falling down effect with these lines, just think of it as rain that is looped

Comment: Ok just read the question you want them to keep going down. Let me see what I can do. Will reply here if I come up with something

Comment: This is too hard for me, I need to explain my written code and with these 2 examples it would be impossible. Is there no other way to simply create lines and animate them to falldown? Thanks for your support!

Comment: I have updated the answer with what you want. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I tried it and it works like a charm, but I have a question. When I change the height from 400px to 100% it goes from the bottom to the top, I want it to go from top to the bottom like on the 400px.

Comment: Let me check and let you know

Comment: It works fine for me even with 100% height. Check if some other style may be wrong

Comment: Can you have a look at my jsfiddle I just made? https://jsfiddle.net/ptyzvfom/#&togetherjs=E2gmlGrKw6

Comment: Check now. I made a change in fiddle . can you see it ?